# Error Code: 3734. Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Working on a small database compiling novel releases across various countries. It worked fine up until I changed the name of Country to countryRel. it started throwing this error code Error Code: 3734.

I've already tried most of the other online help that i can find (such as making the primary key unique) as well as messing around with the variables (adding new ones or getting rid of ones to see what changed, usually this just threw this error Error Code: 1822) Ive put my code back to how I want I would mostly like it to stay. any ideas?

```
create table countries ( counId int unique, countryName varchar(15), primary key(counId));
insert into countries Values (1, 'Japan'),(2, 'America'),(3,'England'),(4,'Germany'),(5,'Canada'),(6,'China');
select * from countries;

drop table countryRel;

create table countryRel (novelId int, counId int, releaseDate date, foreign key(novelId) references 
Lightnovel(novelId), foreign key(counId) references countries(counId));
insert into countryRel values (1, 1, '2019-1-17'),(2, 1, '2019-1-17'),(3, 1, '2019-5-17'),(4, 1, '2019-1-17'),
(5, 1, '2019-1-17'),(6, 1, '2019-1-01'),(7, 1, '2019-1-01'),(8, 1, '2019-2-09'),(9, 1, '2019-2-09'),(1, 2, '2019-9-17'),
(2, 2, '2019-9-20'),(3, 2, '2019-10-10'),(4, 2, '2019-11-21'),(5, 2, '2019-8-04'),(6, 2, '2019-08-04'),
(7, 2, '2019-1-01'),(8, 2, '2019-11-21'),(9, 2, '2019-9-14'),(1, 3, '2019-9-17'),(2, 3, '2019-9-20'),
(3, 3, '2019-10-10'),(4, 3, '2019-11-21'),(5, 3, '2019-8-04'),(6, 3, '2019-08-04'),(7, 3, '2019-1-01'),
(8, 3, '2019-11-21'),(9, 3, '2019-9-14');
```

This should create a small table listing from 1-6 the listed countries. Then,with counId as the main unit pass it to CountryRel to use in it's listed tables.

Comment: You need to create the `Lightnovel` table before you can create the `countryRel` table https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9b58aab6284db3e7e709ea4f919153d1

Comment: my bad, i only shared what was the pertinent code, i do have a lightnovel table,  and didn't feel it would help in this discussion.

Comment: here:  create table Lightnovel (authId int, novelId int, title TEXT, descr TEXT, publisher varchar(45),
Relea date, primary key(novelId), foreign key(authId) references author(authId));

Comment: That doesn't help, as that references another table `author` which you haven't given the definition for. We can't help you solve your problem unless you give us *all* the relevant information.

Comment: create table author(authId int, firstName varchar(30), lastName varchar(30), nationality varchar(15),
firstRelease date, booknum int, primary key(authId));

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and found that you are adding 2 foreign keys but you have not send the table definition for second one (Lightnovel), If I am removing this foreign key script is working fine. Please add tabel Lightnovel then everything will be working fine.

Comment: still trying to figure out the best way to use stack overflows comment system (with two of them) heres my table i didn't add it in this thread because i didn't feel it was pertitenent to the discussion (my bad) :  here:  create table Lightnovel (authId int, novelId int, title TEXT, descr TEXT, publisher varchar(45),
Relea date, primary key(novelId), foreign key(authId) references author(authId));

Comment: when adding a table `LightNovel` there seems to be no problem anymore, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/BKs8DF7e